# Need clarification in theorem about syntactic equations and substitutions

Tags: unification

In the book *"Constraint Handling Rules"*, Thom Frühwirth explains (on p. 50) "Substitutions, variants and equality" over a usual first-order logic language composed of variables, function symbols and predicate symbols.

It's the usual foundation in preparation for introducing unification.

However, one then meets the following text:

> The following classical theorem establishes the relation between
>   syntactic equations and substitutions:
>
> **Theorem 3.1**
>
> Given two expressions $A$ and $B$ and a substitution $\theta = \{X_{1}/t_{1},...,X_{n}/t_{n}\}$, then
>
> $$\forall \theta \space A = B\theta \leftrightarrow (X_{1}=t_{1} \land \cdots \land X_{n}=t_{n} \rightarrow A = B).$$

- "Expressions" are understood to be terms and atomic formulas $p(t_{1},...,t_{n})$ , but also sets, multisets, sequences or lists of terms.
- The subsitution $\theta$ replaces the variables $X_{i}$ by the terms $t_{i}$ in the usual way.

I can't make any sense of the above theorem. It seems badly formulated. Does anyone have the "classical" source?

Comment: If you want to understand unification, you can probably take a look at *Term Rewriting and All That* by Baader and Nipkow.

Comment: As is, the theorem just can't be true because the left hand side is not symetric in $A$ and $B$ while the right hand side is. So by using your theorem twice, you kind of get $A=B\theta  \leftrightarrow B=A\theta$ which is clearly not something you want. One way to fix this (and probably the good one since you're in a chapter speaking of unification) is to replace the left hand side by $A\theta = B\theta$ and interpreting it as "for any $A$, $B$, $\theta$, ($A\theta = B\theta$ iff $\models (X_1=t_1\land \dots\land  X_n=t_n)\rightarrow A=B$)".